# Spatial Mesh do not show in hololens2 emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator

I'm using Hololens 2 emulator version 10.0.19041.1157
MRTK version 2.6.1
Unity Version 2020.1.0a12.1360
Windows 10 64bit

In unity, i can see example mesh loaded from spatial mapping data ["MixedRealityToolkit" GameObject ->Spatial Awareness -> Spatial Objet mesh Observer -> Type ->SpatialObjectMeshObserver]. 
I have attached a script to Gameobject that draws lines on this spatial mapping as attached in screenshot below

```
void Start()
{
    IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem spatialAwarenessSystem;
    spatialAwarenessSystem = CoreServices.SpatialAwarenessSystem;
    spatialAwarenessSystem.ResumeObservers();
}
```

[image: ![[inserted screenshot from unity]]

while building the app to hololens in unity, i'm setting the value 
["MixedRealityToolkit" GameObject ->Spatial Awareness -> Spatial Objet mesh Observer -> Type ->WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver]
I have enabled "SpatialPerception" under Player Settings->Publishing Settings->Capabilities.

There are no build errors, App Deployment from Visual Studio to Hololens emulator is successful [x64, Release]
Note: i have loaded default room in emulator.

upon app start, i don't see spatial mesh in emulator like i used to see in unity.
although i can see spatial mesh in webportal of emulator as shown in below screenshot.

[image: ![inserted screenshot from browser with mesh]

Answer (score 0):

First, we always recommend the latest MRTK version as the best version to develop the MR app, and the current recommendation is to use MRTK 2.7.2. Please review the [Upgrade Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/updates-deployment/updating?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) for guidance on how to upgrading your project.

For the Spatial Mesh does not visible in Hololens2, Spatial Observers are platform-specific components that act as the provider for surfacing various types of mesh data from a platform-specific endpoint. Therefore, please select the [WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.windowsmixedreality.spatialawareness.windowsmixedrealityspatialmeshobserver?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2019-dotnet-2.7.0) class which supports the HoloLens2 platform and modify configuration properties on the observer as necessary:[Configuring mesh observers for the device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/spatial-awareness/configuring-spatial-awareness-mesh-observer?view=mrtkunity-2021-05)

Comment: Like i mentioned in Question, I had selected **WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver** earlier and by default - configuration properties were as shown in the link you shared.
Kindly check screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/xc4CwoL).
I tried with MRTK 2.7.2 and unity 2020.3.14f1 LTS.
 Added the following code as well
`var observer = CoreServices.GetSpatialAwarenessSystemDataProvider<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserve>();  observer.DisplayOption = SpatialAwarenessMeshDisplayOptions.visible; `  
Still i don't see Mesh in Emulator.

Comment: Could you try deploying the BoundaryVisualizationExample.unity which is located at MRTK/Examples/Demos/Boundary/Scenes/ to your device? Do you see the same behavior? We test with this sample and the wireframe is visible in the scene, everything looks works nice (using HoloLens 2 Emulator build 10.0.20348.1010).